# How to drop an index in PostgreSQL 9.6?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have tried below commands as postgres(super) user and the owner user:

```
Drop index <index_name>;
Drop index <index_name> cascade;
Drop index concurrently <index_name>;
```

The query does not give any error but is in the hung state forever till cancelled.

Comment: Your statements are ok in general. You have probably other tasks running in your database which preventing the completion.

Comment: Yes, that can be the case. Is there any way to find out which query/session is using the index?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statements are ok in general. There are other processes having locks on the indices preventing the drop statements from finishing. You can see the active statements with

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

You should set `log_statement` appropriately if necessary.

**Edit:** `pg_locks` will give you information about specific locks:

```
SELECT a.datname,
         c.relname,
         l.transactionid,
         l.mode,
         l.GRANTED,
         a.usename,
         a.query, 
         a.query_start,
         age(now(), a.query_start) AS "age", 
         a.pid 
    FROM  pg_stat_activity a
     JOIN pg_locks         l ON l.pid = a.pid
     JOIN pg_class         c ON c.oid = l.relation
    ORDER BY a.query_start;
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. After closing the dependent sessions, I was able to drop the index.

Comment: @CraigRinger: You are right. I've extended my answer.